# Spring MultiPartFile with special characters in fileName

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, encoding

I own two files Named 18’'filtered.csv and Who’s Driving.ppt that need to be upload using Springs MultiPartFile. Below is the REST URL that handles this.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/content/_upload",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = {"application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public Content postUploadContent(@RequestParam("filename") MultipartFile file,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "contentHost", required = false) String contentHost,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "platform") String platform,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "artifactTypeKey") String artifactTypeKey,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "contentFamilyKey", required = false) String contentFamilyKey,
                                 @PathVariable(value = "nodeCode") String nodeCode) {
```

When I deploy the application in Tomcat and try to upload a file using this REST URL, I get 500 internal server error.

The method **file.getOriginalFilename()** causing this error as there are special chars in the File Name cannot handle by this method.

Tried with UTF-8 encoding on fileName that didn't work.

Please help how to get the file name with exactly the same special chars that were uploaded?

Comment: Anybody can rescue me from this problem?

Comment: Maybe file a bug in the Spring bug tracker (https://jira.spring.io)...